# Oracle record data type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have below code situation that I am having issues with.

---

#### Package Spec.

```
TYPE code_tabletype IS TABLE OF code_rectype
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE code_rectype IS RECORD 
(
  ID   number,
  col1 varcahr2(30),
  col2 varchar2(30)
);

Cursor c1 is select id,col1,col2 from tabl_source;
```

---

#### Function in Package Body

```
retvalue     code_tabletype;
fetch_rec     code_rectype;

...
OPEN c1 into fetch_rec
   LOOP
       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;  
       retvalue (c1%ROWCOUNT) := fetch_rec;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1
...
RETURN retvalue
```

---

I have noticed that when cursor c1 have multiple records. No value is being passed or return in retvalue variable. I have tested this and confirmed this using dbms_output. I am not sure when or what is wrong with the code.

I appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't valid, which doesn't help understand what you are seeing. Do you get an error? Is your function swallowing errors? I can't recall off-hand if rowcount is valid in that scenario. Does using `retvalue.count` as the index instead change the behaviour?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors Alex but I am not sure what you mean by swallowing errors. Do you mean something like this?  retvalue (retvalue.count) := fetch_rec;

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing. Never mind. I am looking at the wrong code. :/